# Clearing input text fields when clicked on in Flash (AS 2.0)

Tags: flash, input, text, field

I have a problem where I want a text field that by default has the word NAME in it, to become empty when a user clicks on it.

The text field has the instance name 'nam' and is inside a movie with the instance name 'input_text'.

I've searched around and found samples of code where everyone keeps suggesting this:

```
textboxinstancename.onSetFocus = function() {
    textboxinstancename.text = "";
};
```

should work. It seems to work for everyone else but me.

I've tried using the following on the first frame of the 'input_text' movie with no luck:

```
this.input_text.nam.onSetFocus = function() {
    this.input_text.nam.text = ""
}
```

I've tried putting this on the first frame of the scene, again with no result:

```
_root.input_text.nam.onSetFocus = function() {
    _root.input_text.nam.text = ""
}
```

I've tried this in the same manner as the last respectively with both 'this' on the instance and '_root' on the scene (denoted by x):

```
x.input_text.nam.onSetFocus = function() {
    if (x.input_text.nam.text == "NAME") {
        x.input_text.nam.text = "";
    }
};
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
semail1.onSetFocus = function() {
    if (semail !== "")
    {
        semail = "";
    }
}
```

I tested myself, its working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

try this on the first frame of the **input_text** movie:

```
nam.onSetFocus = function() {
    nam.text = "";
}
```

(...and make sure that **nam** is present in the first frame)

Also make sure you've set the textfield type to be "Input Text" (there's an option for this in the Properties window.

---

EDIT:

To initialise nam (on your first frame):

```
_root.input_text.nam.text = "NAME";
```

Answer (score 0):

No luck I'm afraid.

Just wondering if this could be getting in the way though:

```
_root.input_text.nam = "NAME";
```

It is on the first frame of the scene.

Comment: If that's meant to be initialising the textfield, it should be _root.input_text.nam.text = "NAME";

Comment: Richard, you're a damn genius. Thanks for pointing that out.
Problem solved; case closed.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. And nothing says 'thanks' like accepting an answer (just click on the big tick-mark beside this answer)!

Comment: No wait, this is YOUR answer... try accepting mine. Thanks :)